# How to get the value of a single row of columns with same name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, rows

I have data frames with same column names so i have merge them

## df1

```
        wave   num   stlines 
0    4050.32   3.0  0.282690
1    4208.98   5.5  0.490580
2    4374.94   9.0  0.714830
3    4379.74   9.0  0.314040
4    4398.01  14.0  0.504150
5    4502.21   8.0  0.562780
```

## df2

```
        wave  num  stlines 
0    4050.32    3  0.28616 
1    4208.98    6  0.48781 
2    4374.94    9  0.71548 
3    4379.74   10  0.31338 
4    4398.01   15  0.49950  
5    4502.21    9  0.56362
```

## df3

```
        wave   num   stlines 
0    4050.32   3.0  0.282690
1    4208.98   7.5  0.490580
2    4374.94   9.0  0.714830
3    4379.74   9.0  0.314040
4    4398.01  14.0  0.504150
5    4502.21   8.0  0.562780
```

after merging, the resultant dataframe looks like this:

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,df3, on='wave',axis=1,join='inner')


      wave   num_x  stlines_x  num_x  stlines_x  num_x  stlines_x 
0    4050.32   3.0  0.282690    3     0.28616      3.0  0.282690
1    4208.98   5.5  0.490580    6     0.48781      5.5  0.490580 
2    4374.94   9.0  0.714830    9     0.71548      9.0  0.714830
3    4379.74   9.0  0.314040   10     0.31338      9.0  0.314040
4    4398.01  14.0  0.504150   15     0.49950     14.0  0.504150
5    4502.21   8.0  0.562780    9     0.56362      8.0  0.562780
```

So now if i want to take the values of all the coulmns with name`num_x` for any row. Then how can i get them?

I can get the complete columns with same name using the following

```
df.num_x

    num   num   num
 0    3    3.0    3
 1  5.5      6  7.5 
 2    9    9.0    9
 3   10   14.0   10 
 4   15    8.0   15
 5    9    3.0    9
```

but when i tried to do the same for a single row '1' then it didn't work:

```
df.num_x['1']
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
    num   num   num
 1  5.5     6    7.5
```

How can i get them??

Comment: Try `df.num_x.loc[:, '1']`?

Comment: yep i've tried that already @576i

Comment: I made an edit abovr.... I misread your question, try again

Comment: Same thing.! didn't work

Comment: I just tested that in jupyter, it's the other way around. df.loc['1']. To get it back to dataframe,`pd.DataFrame(df.loc['1']).T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[1, 'num_x']
```

---

In pandas same columns names are problematic, because not easy seelct first, second `num_x`, so suggest create `MultiIndex`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

df = pd.concat([x.set_index('wave') for x in dfs], 
               axis=1, 
               keys=['df1','df2','df3'], join='inner')
print (df)
          df1          df2            df3         
          num  stlines num  stlines   num  stlines
wave                                              
4050.32   3.0  0.28269   3  0.28616   3.0  0.28269
4208.98   5.5  0.49058   6  0.48781   7.5  0.49058
4374.94   9.0  0.71483   9  0.71548   9.0  0.71483
4379.74   9.0  0.31404  10  0.31338   9.0  0.31404
4398.01  14.0  0.50415  15  0.49950  14.0  0.50415
4502.21   8.0  0.56278   9  0.56362   8.0  0.56278
```

And then use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for selecting:

```
df1 = df.xs('num', axis=1, level=1)
print (df1)
          df1  df2   df3
wave                    
4050.32   3.0    3   3.0
4208.98   5.5    6   7.5
4374.94   9.0    9   9.0
4379.74   9.0   10   9.0
4398.01  14.0   15  14.0
4502.21   8.0    9   8.0
```

Comment: And how exactly does it answers my question?